# statistical disclosure control: finding 2/3 anonymity violations (or, how to find items in one data frame that are missing in the other)

Tags: r, privacy

I'm learning about data anonymization and would like to anonymize a dataset, in this case the adult dataset from https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/adult, which I loaded using

```
library(sdcMicro)
data <- read.table("/home/thijser/Downloads/adult.data",sep=",")
sdc <- createSdcObj(ndata, keyVars = c('V4','V9','V10'),sensibleVar= c('V7','V1'))
```

I know that I can also get back the data by using

```
 mdat<-extractManipData(sdc, ignoreKeyVars = FALSE, 
  ignoreParamVars = FALSE, ignoreNumVars = FALSE,
  ignoreGhostVars = FALSE, ignoreStrataVar = FALSE)
```

and "2-anonymity" means that no record can uniquely be identified by the values in column 4,9 and 10 while "3-anonymity" means that at least 3 records share all permutations of column 4,9 and 10 that exist in the database.

Now this already gives me only 7 2-anonymity violations and I would like to know what they are… Is there any method to get the sdc to tell me which records are in violation?

As an alternative I can also use

```
sde <- localSupression(sdc,2) 
mdat2 <- extractManipData(sdc, ignoreKeyVars = FALSE, 
   ignorePramVars = FALSE, ignoreNumVars = FALSE, 
   ignoreGhostVars = FALSE, ignoreStrataVar = FALSE)
```

in order to generate a list in `mdat2` that is missing the records in `mdat`, but that requires me to find all records that are in one list but not in the other.

Answer (score 1):

Try the command below. It should display the key variables that violate 3-anonymity:

`data[sdc@risk$individual[,2]<3,selectedKeyVars]   #displays key variables that violate 3-anonymity`